# VBA Loop through multiple httprequest and store data in excel 2010

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have 5 excels which i use with winhttprequest to get data in excel.I would like to put all the requests in one vba script and then loop through them and store the data in just one sheet one quote after another.

Also the header doesnt get stored as the first column but there are two rows which are left blank for them.What am i not getting?

I cant use IE objects as i have to use request headers as well and it took too long to build even this mechanism.

Below is my code:

```
Sub ParseTable()

Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument 'Document object
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements
Dim ieURL As String 'URL

Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument 'Get responseText in

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTSTK&symbol=INFY&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=week&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=", False
        '-----------below are the urls which to loop through --------------------'
        'https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTSTK&symbol=TCS&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=week&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=
        'https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTSTK&symbol=DLF&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=week&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm"
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With


MsgBox oHtml.body.innerHTML

Set htmldoc = oHtml 'Document webpage
Set eleColtr = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags

'This section populates Excel
i = 0 'start with first value in tr collection
For Each eleRow In eleColtr 'for each element in the tr collection
    Set eleColtd = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
    j = 0 'start with the first value in the td collection
    For Each eleCol In eleColtd 'for each element in the td collection
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value = eleCol.innerText 'paste the inner text of the td element, and offset at the same time
        j = j + 1 'move to next element in td collection
    Next eleCol 'rinse and repeat
    i = i + 1 'move to next element in td collection
Next eleRow 'rinse and repeat

'Remove Commas in the cells mostly with Numbers.Doesnt really work but makes the number right side oriented which makes the work done.
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace what:=",", replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Right now it just shows one quote per excel that too without headers but below output would be my preference for further calculations.

[image: Desired O/P]

Where as right now i get data like below in individual excels.

[image: Output right now]

Comment: So, do you want headers or not? And will you be refreshing this over time and expecting the results to be in the same place in the sheet?

Comment: Yes..i need headers but only at the top once..not for all of the subsequent quotes.
This i would refresh daily and remove the data longer then the period required.I would keep 1 year data and delete whichever is coming before that.

Comment: Does it matter if you have the headers repeated? I am thinking of a method which is very quick but would repeat headers.

Comment: this is only for 3 quotes..ideally i would be putting in more than 100 quotes.
Will there be any way to remove the headers afterwards and then shift cells up?

Comment: Do you want the empty rows removed?

Comment: empty rows where? iyes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ParseTables()
    Dim oHtml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long, j As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim tableNumber As Long, hTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable, symbols(), startRow As Long

    symbols = Array("INFY", "TCS", "DLF")
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        For i = LBound(symbols) To UBound(symbols)
            tableNumber = tableNumber + 1
            .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTSTK&symbol=" & symbols(i) & "&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=week&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=", False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm"
            .send
            oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set hTable = oHtml.querySelector("table")
            startRow = IIf(tableNumber = 1, GetLastRow(ws, 1), GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1)
            WriteTable hTable, tableNumber, startRow, ws
        Next
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Range("A1:A" & GetLastRow(ws, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.UsedRange.Replace What:=",", replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, ByVal tableNumber As Long, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    r = startRow
    With ws
        If tableNumber = 1 Then
            Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long, headerCount As Long
            Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
            For Each header In headers
                If headerCount > 0 Then
                    columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
                    .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
                End If
                headerCount = headerCount + 1
            Next header
            startRow = startRow + 1
        End If
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tr In tRow
            r = r + 1
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            c = 1
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: this works but if i re run it or add a new  quote it again saves full data from new line ..ie. same copy of the data stored again with headers.

Comment: Nice..pls mention if i understood the code correctly:
1.Starting with headercount>1 so that the description headers are not put in the excel.
2.GetLastRow will return the last row and we will input data from lastrow +1.
3.What does on Error resume next and onerror goto clause does?

Comment: I use tableNumber to determine if first table and therefore consider headers. I use headerCount to exclude the very first th element which has _Historical Contract-wise Price Volume Data_ . And correct for GetLastRow. On Error Resume Next is overkill as we expect there to be blank rows but just in case there are not I am using that to suppress user seeing a warning about no blank rows.

Comment: Yes..what was the fastest method?the one which you mentioned that would have not left out headers for each data set?

Comment: ok so full data for every quote would be copied to clipboard and then at the very end paste the data correct?

Comment: looked it up..Would that be using a new DataObject of MSForms?

Comment: Also do you think performance wise would it be fine to put up 100quotes in the same excel..This would be 1year data of 100 quotes with three entries per day?

Comment: Also when i am using below array Array("INFY", "TCS", "DLF", "SUNPHARMA", "ACC", "OIL", "MARUTI") i am getting object variable or with block variable not set vba excel. Why is this error occuring?

Comment: There is a server side problem: I see the following response: _The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to
complete your request_ This seems to occur for SUNPHARMA onwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184959/discussion-between-anis-shaikh-and-qharr).

Comment: i see the same error for below as well:Array("INFY", "TCS", "DLF", "ACC", "OIL")
where can we see the response? internal error one

Comment: should i add dim and set for all objects to assign value?

Comment: Happens when i use just one value too:
symbols = Array("OIL").
can this be server related too?I am not able to see the server error.
Is that why IE objects are used?

Comment: it worked during market hours..i got a question..if this occurs for one.ie getting a server error or any other error for a quote..is there any way to leave that and skip to the next one?

Comment: Hey @QHarr..i just noticed that the excel fetched only top 100 rows and not all of the rows..Even in the referer website the first 100 rows are shown and all of the rows are download when we click on Download file in CSV format and a csv file is downloaded. Is there any way to get all the rows in our excel?

Comment: Yes.
Step 1: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm
Go to this website,now select instrument as stock futures,symbol can be any symbol but for eg.INFY,year 2018,now go straight to radio button for past and select anything over 3month..like even 3 month.So the table which will be shown in the website would be of around 100 rows and the real full data would come only when we click on download the data in csv.
This is whats happening in our excel as well.We are only getting the data which is displayed on the website ie. 100 rows and not the full data.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ii7yGtkr..check this out pls.This will get data only till nov as that is around 100th row and rest till dec today we wont.

Comment: this is really a new question then I suspect. This question is how to get same number of rows as in csv download. Is there a reason why you don't automate the csv download?

Comment: then i wont get a consolidated all symbols in one excel right..i mainly want 1month to 1year data of all the stocks in one excel...Pastebin link is: https://pastebin.com/ii7yGtkr

Comment: No not for a single symbol..the code would be for many symbols..ideally i was going to break it into 50 in one excel and 50 in other.Powerquery wont work for Excel 2010 right?
I couldnt find any link from clicking on download button for csv..if it is possible to get a consolidated one after looping through the symbols that also would work.If you could take me through this then also great.

Comment: Apparently some editions of 2010 support powerquery add-in. Not sure if covered in this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwW2CDdvUUs

Comment: i do have excel 2016 as well.Only reason i was using 2010 is it was simple in look and feel.If the full download isnt possible with the current code i would like to start with your new plan..Where should i begin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185435/discussion-between-qharr-and-anis-shaikh).

Comment: Hey Qharr..i think i have got the issue..I inspected the source and there is a hidden div called csvContentDiv which puts data in the csv file.If you turn on the network and record activity in chrome and then you see the request,request headers,response and response headers.Then if you will copy the response to a notepad you will see there are total 3 divs.1 is the div that has 100 rows,next is a  Note div and third is the remaining data div with id csvContentDiv.It has comma separated data that looks like JSON because of ":".Can you pls help to add that div in our excel?

Comment: Hi QHarr.. I have added data successfully now(solved the hidden div problem) but i am stuck on creating charts with vba.Would you be willing to help/guide with below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573392/create-multiple-charts-using-same-x-axis-data-in-vba
@QHarr