# How to scrape data from the table on all pages?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, pagination

I am extracting data from a website and my code only extracts the first two pages.

I tried putting a for loop but it doesn't navigate to the other pages.

Here is the HTML Code:

```html
<div class="dataTables_length" id="activitylog_table_length"><label>Show <select name="activitylog_table_length" aria-controls="activitylog_table" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="500">500</option></select> entries</label></div>



<div class="dataTables_info" id="activitylog_table_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 10 of 668 entries</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" id="activitylog_table_paginate"><ul class="pagination">
<li class="paginate_button page-item first disabled" id="activitylog_table_first">
<a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" class="page-link">
<i class="la la-angle-double-left"></i></a></li><li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" id="activitylog_table_previous">
<a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" class="page-link">
<i class="la la-angle-left"></i>
</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" class="page-link">1</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0" class="page-link">2</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0" class="page-link">3</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0" class="page-link">4</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0" class="page-link">5</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item disabled" id="activitylog_table_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" class="page-link">…</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0" class="page-link">67</a>
</li><li class="paginate_button page-item next" id="activitylog_table_next">
<a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="9" tabindex="0" class="page-link">
<i class="la la-angle-right"></i>
</a><
/li><li class="paginate_button page-item last" id="activitylog_table_last"><a href="#" aria-controls="activitylog_table" data-dt-idx="10" tabindex="0" class="page-link"><i class="la la-angle-double-right"></i></a></li></ul></div></div>
```

Sub Extract()

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim btn As Object
Dim temp As Object
Dim Table As Object
Dim tRows As Object
Dim rNum As Integer
Dim cNum As Integer
Dim tCells As Object
Dim np As Variant
Dim numPages As String
Dim url As String
Dim pages As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer
Dim NextHref As String
Dim NextURL As String

url = "https://admin.timesheetmobile.com/mr2/new/activity.php"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = False

' Navigate to the webpage
ie.navigate url

 ' Wait while the page is loading
 While ie.Busy
      DoEvents
 Wend
 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
 ' Wait an additional 3 seconds for good measure


Dim numPages As String
Set temp = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("dataTables_info")

numPages = temp(0).innerText

pos = Mid(numPages, 20, 3)
np = Round(pos, 0)

 rNum = 1
 cNum = 1

  Set Table = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("dataTables_scrollBody")

    Set tRows = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

    Set tHead = Table(0).getElementsByTagName("th")

    For Each h In tHead
        Sheet6.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = h.innerText
        cNum = cNum + 1
    Next

    rNum = rNum + 1
    cNum = 1

For i = 1 To np

        Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")

        For Each c In tCells

            Sheet6.Cells(rNum, cNum).Value = c.innerText

            cNum = cNum + 1
        Next

        rNum = rNum + 1
        cNum = 1

    Next


    Set btn = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("paginate_button page-item next")
    btn(0).Click



Next

 ' Clear the ie object. This probably isn't necessary, but helps
 ' clean things up
Set ie = Nothing
```

End Sub

I would like it to extract all the data from pages 1 to np.  Is this possible? Or are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit pseudo code but outlines extracting the number of pages and then clicking the next button until all pages visited. I use an id selector for the next button as is faster and more robust than a compound class selector.

I work off ie.document throughout to avoid stale element exceptions bubbling up as errors in loop over pages.

Depending on how you want table info written out you might be able to store info in an array; otherwise perhaps write out tables during the loop by finding the next available row in the sheet..... I show how to write to next available row in a prior SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692293/6241235). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135557/6241235) answer shows you how to use the clipboard to post table to next row during loop.

A better way would be if you can authenticate and get all info via [XHR](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) requests but impossible to tell if that is possible at present.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, numPages As Long, length As Long

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "loginURL"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'login stuff here ....

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            length = .querySelectorAll(".page-link").length
            numPages = CLng(.querySelectorAll(".page-link").item(length - 3).innerText)
            'Assume on page 1 and extract last page number from length -2 (ignoring data-dt-idx="10" and data-dt-idx="9"
            'do something with page 1 then click through next button for num of pages
            For i = 2 To numPages
                .querySelector("#activitylog_table_next").Click
                .querySelector("[data-dt-idx='" & i + 1 & "']").click  'alternate
                While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                'do something with other pages
            Next
            Stop '<=delete me later
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To set to 500 per page

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='500']").Selected = True
```

Comment: Hello, an error shows at the code "numPages = CLng(.querySelectorAll(".page-link").item(length - 3).innerText)" it shows Object required (Error 424).

Comment: Put a wait before hand Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2) increase 2 if required

Comment: Hello,  unfortunately it doesn't work it still says Object Required (Error 424)

Comment: Even with longer waits? Also, did you verify the element is not within a parent iframe/frame?

Comment: I don't think I have verified it.  Sorry.

Comment: Have a look and see

Comment: Hello,  Sorry for the late reply.  No, the element is not within a parent iframe/frame.

Comment: I tested with your html read in from a file and it worked fine so unsure what other than html I can't see or timing could be the issue.

Comment: Hello, so sorry for the delay in replying.  You are right it worked.  The problem was that the Next Button doesn't work for the next pages.  You can click it from page 1 to 2 but not to the other pages. So when you click from Page 2 to Page 3 the next button doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I edited in an alternate:  .querySelector("[data-dt-idx='" & i + 1 & "']").click

Comment: could you also explain what doesn't work means? Any error ? Or simply doesn't change pages ? Do you notice any change in the html during the click manually?

Comment: It doesn't change pages once it reaches page 2.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much it works now but the problem is that it jumps from page 5 to the last page "data-dt-idx="8"

Comment: Is there an ellipsis? ... Yes there is! activitylog_table_ellipsis

Comment: You need to study the behaviour around the ellipsis.... when you manually click what happens to the numbering when you reach the ellipsis? What happens with the data-dt-idx?

Comment: Hello, what happens is that it automatically goes to the next page.  For example you are on Page 4, then the remaining buttons are Page 5 then the ellipsis...then when you click Page 5, Page 6 shows up then the ellipsis moves after Page 6...

Comment: What if we use another method?  Such as we use the Dropdown (I added the code above) then choose probably 200 or 500 items on one page then we can just do without the ellipsis bothering the code?

Comment: And what happens with the data-dt-idx numbering for the new numbers?

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("[value='500']").Selected = True

Comment: Hello,  Thank you very much and it was a great help.  Right now, the error code shows MS Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.  What I do is just click OK several times once it pops up and wait for the web site to load.  Is there anyway not to show this?

Comment: Add a DoEvents before